# Find the Schwarz-Christoffel transformation of the upper half-plane $U$ onto the region

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the Schwarz-Christoffel transformation of the upper half-plane $U$ onto the region[image]

what I have done is considering the other region:[image]

let $x_1=-1,\ x_2=0,\ w_1=ia,\ w_2=-R$, then we have $\theta_1=-\frac{\pi}{2}, \ \theta_2=\pi$ and $\alpha_1=\frac{1}{2}, \alpha_2=-1$, so we get $f'(z)=A(z+1)^\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}$ and $f(z)=A(2\sqrt{z+1}+\ln|\frac{\sqrt{z+1}-1}{\sqrt{z+1}+1}|)+B$

My question is: how can I find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I don't understand which region you are mapping onto. If it's the one with  $-R$, then why are the angles $-\pi/2$ and $\pi$? Generally, having $\infty$ as a vertex is a *good* thing; I don't see what you win by replacing it with $-R$.